# Atributo de tipo clase: ¿como acceder a métodos de la clase original?

Tags: java

Buenos días. A ver si me explico:

Tengo 2 clases creadas dentro del mismo paquete y no son padre-hija. La clase 1 tiene sus atributos y sus métodos. La clase 2 tiene sus atributos con la particularidad de que uno de estos es un atributo del tipo clase 1. Por ejemplo, clase 1:

```
`public class Cliente {

private int idCliente;
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private String telefono;

}`
```

Clase 2:

```
`public abstract class Cuenta {

protected int numeroDeCuenta;
protected double saldo;
protected Cliente titular;

}`
```

Osea, el atributo "titular" de la clase 2, es un atribut del tipo clase. Pues bien, a la hora de probar el programa, creo un objeto del tipo clase "Cliente" y otro del tipo clase "CuentaCorriente" (esta es una clase hija de la clase "Cuenta", ya que esta es abstracta y no permite instanciar :

```
`Cliente usuario2 = new Cliente (0000001, "Fulanito López", "C/ Madrid 95, 
3ºA", "669541985");`

`CuentaCorriente cuenta_corriente_usuario2 = new CuentaCorriente (0000001, 
5000, usuario2);`
```

Pues aqui el problema: ¿no se supone que si pongo cuenta_corriente_usuario2. deberia de salir una lista con los metodos disponibles de ambas clases? Lo que quiero es acceder desde el objeto "cuenta_corriente_usuario2" a los métodos de la clase "Ciente". No puedo poner que sean padre-hija, ni static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder acceder a los métodos del objeto `titular` de tipo `Cliente`, primero tienes que acceder a el.

Lo cual lo puedes hacer obteniendo el objeto `titular` y después accediendo a sus métodos.

```
Cliente cliente = cuenta_corriente_usuario2.getTitular();
int idCliente = cliente.getIdCliente();
```

O puedes acceder directamente a sus métodos.

```
int idCliente = cuenta_corriente_usuario2.getTitular().getIdCliente();
```

Comment: Perfecto, la segunda forma era como quería. Lo tenía frente a la narices y no daba con ello, muchas gracias!

Comment: @MeN para acceder a el objeto `titular` y a sus métodos estoy dando por hecho que tienes creados los métodos getter.

Comment: Sisi, esta todo creado, lo que que no podía acceder y era que no usaba bien el modo de acceso. Con tu ejemplo me sirvió:

`int idCliente = cuenta_corriente_usuario2.getTitular().getIdCliente();`